# Call aspect based on return value

Tags: java, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I am using Spring AOP. This is the sample method:

```
public String method(List<Integer> ids) {
    if(ids == null) return "ERROR";
    else return "OK";
}
```

My aspect looks like this:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution( * com.pack.MyService.method(..))", returning = "result")
public void methodAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, String result) {
    // My implementation
}
```

Is it possible to call or not to call aspect method based on the retunt value of `method()`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider throwing an exception instead of returning a error value from the function. If you are throwing an exception you might consider doing something like this.

Let us rewrite your function again.

```
public String method(List<Integer> ids) throws Exception {
    if(ids == null)
        throw new RunTimeException("ERROR");

    return "OK";
}
```

Now your aspect might look like this.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "class() && execution( * com.pack.MyService.method(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void onMethodExecutionFailure(Exception ex) {
    log.debug(ex.getMessage());
    // Your implementation
}

@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution( * com.pack.MyService.method(..))")
public void onMethodExecutionSuccess(String result) {
    log.debug("Success!");
    // Your success implementation
}
```

The `pointcut` and the parameters of the function are just for example. Please modify them as your need. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not the solution for me.

Comment: I support this solution because returning error values it not Java or OOP, it is a lapse back into the bad old times of C and procedural programming before exceptions were invented. Of course you can also use an `if()` qualifier in your pointcut, but it will also be evaluated during runtime just like if-else code within the advice itself. That you have this requirement at all just proves that your application design is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put your "if/else logic" in your methodAdvice which can get the result from your method call, if the result is "ERROR", just return, or do the else logic.